# Excel VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when opening workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a VBA that where I try to open a workbook as follows (I shortened the alue of strtempalte for clarity)

```
strTemplate = iPath + "\LivretScolaire.xlsx"
If Dir(strTemplate) = "" Then
          MsgBox "The carnet for " + strPrenomEtudiant + " does not exist"
          End
Else
                    
     Set templateWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(strTemplate)
End If
```

The code always errors on Workbooks.Open(strTemplate) as follows

[image]

[image]

Even I hard-coded the path to file instead of the variable strTemplate but getting the same error. What is strange, I wrote the VBA code on an excel on a desktop where it works fine, this error I am getting when I transferred the whole directory to my laptop so the error is happening on the laptop

Comment: Can you open the file manually in Excel?

Comment: What extension does `strTemplate` have? In fact, please show us the value of `strTemplate`...

Comment: If you paste the value of `strTemplate` into the File Explorer address bar does it open the file?  Type `?strTemplate` into VB Immediate Window to get the value - `Ctrl+G` to open the Immediate window if it's not already.

Comment: Hi darren, I have just responded to my question in order to respond to your questions and be able to show what happens when I open the file

Comment: Following my response, after discovering why getting this error, I did a test, instead of using my template to copy to and save it, I used a blank new excel workbook and getting the exact same problem, conditional fomatting copy is the root  of the problem, I also updated the code to use the following 3 statements                      rngEtudiant.Copy   templateWorkbook.Worksheets("CARNET").Range(strCellToStartTCoy).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            templateWorkbook.Worksheets("CARNET").Range(strCellToStartTCoy).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

Comment: so the issue boils down to the copy/paste of a range from source to target workbook with nconditional formatting

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I have just discovered why I am getting this error. In my VBA code I open a new file to paste a Range (with conditional formatting for coloring cells according to enetered caracter v or b or x) for the first run, then in the 2nd run I check if file exists and do the same thing, copyingh another range to it.

When I open the file in question before the 2nd run, I get the following message

[image]

I accept to repair, the workbook opens but without the formatting colors in the destination range

[image]

I close and save the workbook then I do the 2nd run it goes through without the error

So it seems while copying the Range/Cells with the following code

```
rngEtudiant.Copy Destination:=templateWorkbook.Worksheets("CARNET").Range(strCellToStartTCoy)
           
     If bUseExistingFile Then
         templateWorkbook.Save
         templateWorkbook.Close
      Else
          templateWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strTemplatePerEtudiant
          templateWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
      End If
```